# Linode Setup Queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vps, linode

I am extremely new to the world of VPS's so wondered if anyone had links to any guides on installing the following on a Linode VPS?

I can find guides that show how to setup parts of this but not all these in one guide. I just don;t want to get anything wrong.

RVM,
Rails,
Nginx,
PostgreSQL

Maybe Passenger but not 100% what Passenger is or if I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linode offers you servers in many Linux flavours. 
The right question should be how to install the tools you need in Debian or CentOs, or whichever Distribution you wish to use. 
Passenger is used to deploy Ruby applications and not to setup the server.